# Rest/SOAP API workflow for flight booking and payment

Tags: sabre

Is there a workflow for making payments to the airlines and getting the flight ticket after the InstaFlight search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of EnhancedAirBook and PassengerDetails APIs to create a reservation including your selected flights from InstaFlights:

In order to issue a ticket afterwards, you can use the API AirTicketLLSRQ - here's a workflow that explains how to use it:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/workflows/issue_air_ticket

The same API - AirTicketLLSRQ - accepts the form of payment information.
For some markets and credit cards you can use another API to get credit card approval:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/fulfill/get_credit_card_approval

So, in summary, the APIs sequence would be:
 - InstaFlights (or any other air shopping service)
 - EnhancedAirBook + PassengerDetails APIs
 - Optionally - if using credit card payment - use the Get Credit Card 
   Approval API (or any other payment gateway of your choice)
 - DesignatePrinter + AirTicketLLSRQ to issue the tickets

For other sample workflows, please refer to github, that includes sample requests and explanation:
https://github.com/sabredevstudio/sabreapisworkflows

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this sequence.

Comment: You mentioned '_(or any other payment gateway of your choice)_'. So what API should I use if I want to connect external payment gateways to Sabre?

Comment: It's not that you will connect them to Sabre, you would basically get the authorization code for your transaction, and then use it in AirTicketLLSRQ within the credit card payment details.

Comment: Okay, I tried to access SOAP API. Should I have special privileges for accessing SOAP API for even development? Because I tried to use SessionCreateRQ and TokenCreateRQ with my username and password, but the response is always 'authentication failed'.

Comment: Yes, you need to request access. The credentials you get when you register in Dev Studio will work only for REST APIs.

You can request SOAP access via: https://developer.sabre.com/contact or webservices.support@sabre.com