# Authentication error on EnhancedAirBookRQ

Tags: sabre

I used *BinarySecurityToken* for EnhancedAirBookRQ, but I receive `USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED`. I used the same token for BargainFinderMaxRQ and it worked.  Should I get another set of test credentials for the sequence provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021897/6919253)?

**Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
              xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"
              xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
<soapenv:Header>
    <sec:Security>
        <sec:BinarySecurityToken>--Token--</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
    </sec:Security>
    <mes:MessageHeader>
        <mes:From>
            <mes:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</mes:PartyId>
        </mes:From>
        <mes:To>
            <mes:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</mes:PartyId>
        </mes:To>
        <mes:CPAId>--CPAId--</mes:CPAId>
        <mes:ConversationId>eservices@sabre.com</mes:ConversationId>
        <mes:Service mes:type="sabreXML">sabreXML</mes:Service>
        <mes:Action>EnhancedAirBookRQ</mes:Action>
        <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>00000</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>233</mes:Timestamp>
        </mes:MessageData>
        <mes:Description xml:lang="en-US">Testing</mes:Description>
    </mes:MessageHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <EnhancedAirBookRQ version="3.7.0" HaltOnError="true">
        <OTA_AirBookRQ>
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-11-15T10:05:00" FlightNumber="241" NumberInParty="2"
                               ResBookDesigCode="F" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="ATL"/>
                    <MarketingAirline Code="US" FlightNumber="241"/>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="LAS"/>
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
        </OTA_AirBookRQ>
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
</soapenv:Body>
```

**Response:**

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"
                      xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
        <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">ws</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:From>
        <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">from</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>--CPAId--</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:ConversationId>eservices@sabre.com</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">sabreXML</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>2308814425665870610</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2016-11-08T11:49:26</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>00000</eb:RefToMessageId>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">--Token--</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
    <soap-env:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthorizationFailed</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Authorization failed</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthorizationException:
                errors.authorization.USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED
            </StackTrace>
        </detail>
    </soap-env:Fault>
</soap-env:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an API agreement? Looks like your credentials don't have the appropiate authorization to consume that service.

In case you do have a contract, I'd advise you to contact the helpdesk so they can revise your credentials.

Comment: I contacted Sabre support to get the test credentials to access SOAP APIs for application development. I received the credentials and generated the token and used it, but it works for some API calls (like BargainFinderMaxRQ) and doesn't work for some (like EnhancedAirBookRQ). And okay, I'll contact Sabre support.

Comment: Are you creating calling CreateToken or CreateSession?

Comment: Used CreateToken. But I tried with CreateSession too, but did not work.

Comment: Seems like something tied to your credentials assigned, would recommend contacting Sabre support for validation.